Reduction for Subset Maximizing Profit
Consider a set of elements $\mathcal{E}$  where we define Profit for each pair of elements $e_1, e_2 \in \mathcal{E}$ as $P(e_1, e_2)$. The objective is to find a subset $\mathcal{E}_s$ such that the total sum of the profits between any two elements in the subset is maximized, \begin{equation*}
    \max \sum_{\substack{e_1, e_2 \in \  \mathcal{E}_s \\ e_1 \neq e_2}} P(e_1, e_2), 
    \end{equation*}
The first question is does the above maximization statement capture the subset maximization objective? And secondly, I am trying to do a reduction from the Maximum Weighted Clique Problem wherein we want to show that if for the decision version of the clique problem there exists a $k$-clique with weight $T$, there exists a subset of size $k$. But in this scenario would the same weight $T$ apply to the subset as well?
